# GitKraken: An external application is performing a rebase on this repository

Tags: gitkraken

Hi I just changed my email on all the commits in my project. After I ran this script from the terminal all worked good.

Now I have an error in the GitKraken dashboard with the following error:
[image]

How do I remove it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed: put the following in the CLI `git rebase --abort`

Basically since I ran the script the above is stuck in a rebase process until I abort it.

Make sure to not create a new branch when rebasing and then exiting otherwise it will duplicate the git commits.